# Suppress datamember attribute name JSON

Tags: json, wcf, serialization, datamember

I have an issue serializing to JSON moving from an IList<"string"> to an IList<"customobject">. The endpoint is expecting an array of strings such as :-

```
"options": [
    "foo1",
    "foo2"
  ]
```

With the customobject I am getting the following :-

```
"options": [
    {
      "name": "foo1"
    },
    {
      "name": "foo2"
    }
]
```

Is there any way to suppress name attribute and continue to get an array of strings with WCF, or do I have to do it another way? Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Would still appreciate any insight into the possibility of doing this, but for now has been resolved by adding the option as a string as well as an object, and only exporting the string. I know this is duplication, but will have to wait for an update to the endpoint.